# getting or copying texlive 2013 for Mac

Tags: texlive, mactex

I migrated to a new machine (Mac) and need a texlive 2013 installation there. I thought I could just copy over all files from my old machine, but this does not seem to work since the preference pane does not know about the 2013 files, so I cannot activate texlive 2013. I vaguely remember that there is just a symbolic link to be set, but I cannot find this information. So: is there a way to fix this quickly or is there a place where I can download the Mactex 2013 package? I found webpages offering this, but they all link to the current MacTex package (although claiming differently).

Comment: A 2013 image of TeXLive can be found here: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/

Comment: Does this work with Mac? Mactex is usually a huge package with the .pkg ending. It does the integration with the Mac preference pane.

Comment: I am no Mac user, but you asked about TeXLive 2013 ...

Comment: @StefanMüller, did you browse that link? If you go up, the mactex are on another branch: ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/mactex/2013/

Comment: Well, I have a pgf problem (xelatex) that was introduced in 2014. It is not fixed yet. It is related to the tixmark package and subnode command (I asked a question about it here and filed a bug report, but the bug is still there). http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229500/tikzmark-and-xelatex Maybe I just do not use subnode and position the arrows by hand ...