# Wrong marginnote positions inside a tikzpicture with XeLaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, marginnote

The `marginnote` package offers the `\marginnote` macro. I use this inside a `tikzpicture` environment to place notes into the margin.

While this works without problems when compiling with pdfLaTeX, this gives horizontal shifts when compiling with XeLaTeX.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This line\marginnote{ABC} contains a margin note.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \node[right] at (1,0) {This line\marginnote{ABC} contains a margin note.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compilation (twice) with pdfLaTeX (using MiKTeX on Windows) gives the expected result:

[image]

Compilation with XeLaTeX (using MiKTeX on Windows) gives shifts the second note inside the `tikzpicture`:

[image]

Can this code be modified to compile correctly for pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX?

Comment: I get the same with TeX Live on Mac OS X. Seems a problem with the XeTeX driver for PGF.

Comment: Possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229500/tikzmark-and-xelatex

Comment: When Can I ask you a my problem?

Comment: @egreg I am a little bit puzzled. This question was marked as duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339827/draw-connection-between-node-in-forest-tree-diagram-and-something-outside-it. Unfortunately, I cannot see any connection between my question and that one of the link. What am I missing?

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm Wrong action, sorry. Reopened

Comment: @egreg No problem - I just thought that I was too stupid to see the point ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Again, the solution [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339975/51022), which is simply copying the definition from `pgfsys-common-pdf-via-dvi.def`.

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@hboxsynced#1{%
  {%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
    \setbox\pgf@hbox=\hbox{%
      \hskip\pgf@pt@x%
      \raise\pgf@pt@y\hbox{%
        \pgf@pt@x=0pt%
        \pgf@pt@y=0pt%
        \special{pdf: content q}%
        \pgflowlevelsynccm% 
        \pgfsys@invoke{q -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm}%
        \special{pdf: content -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm q}% translate to original coordinate system
        \pgfsys@invoke{0 J [] 0 d}% reset line cap and dash
        \wd#1=0pt%
        \ht#1=0pt%
        \dp#1=0pt%
        \box#1%
        \pgfsys@invoke{n Q Q Q}%
      }%
      \hss%
    }%
    \wd\pgf@hbox=0pt%
    \ht\pgf@hbox=0pt%
    \dp\pgf@hbox=0pt%
    \pgfsys@hbox\pgf@hbox%
    \pgfsys@endscope%
  }%
}
\makeatother


This line\marginnote{ABC} contains a margin note.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \fill[red] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \node[right] at (1,0) {This line\marginnote{ABC} contains a margin note.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as your first picture.

I did not raise the duplicate-vote because the last one I do so, someone doubt that it is the case.

Comment: Thank you for providing this helpful answer. The linked question (which is one year younger than mine) has several answers also containing further links which clouded the solution for me ... So, it's good to have an answer on this place :-)