# How can I adjust horizontal alignment of \marginnote?

Tags: tcolorbox, marginnote

When I use \marginnote inside a tcolorbox, it is shifted horizontally, as shown in the attached figure.
Sorry for the lack of MWE -- this is a PreTeXt-generated LaTeX file, with about 1000 lines of preamble code.

My page geometry is:
`\geometry{inner=1in,textheight=9in,textwidth=320pt,marginparwidth=150pt,marginparsep=24pt,bottom=1in,footskip=29pt,showframe}`

Divisions such as example, theorem, etc. are styled with tcolorbox. We use \marginnote to shift some figures to the margin. If a margin figure is inside a tcolorbox (like `example`) it gets shifted to the right.

I've tried adding a `\noindent` and `\hskip-12pt` before and after the `\marginnote` declaration but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

The image below shows one margin figure that's declared within an example, and further down the page, a figure that's not within an example. Frame borders are turned on to help illustrate.

[image: a page displaying the shifting of a figure within a tcolorbox]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I tracked it down. [Non-obvious duplicate here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269426/wrong-marginnote-positions-inside-a-tikzpicture-with-xelatex)

It's an `xelatex` issue.