# custom margin notes

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, marginpar, marginnote

I am trying to set up a custom margin note command for my lecture notes but I encountered a few problems.

First of all, this is how it should look:

[image: margin notes]

As you can see in the screenshot above, the margin notes are numbered (I tried to mimic footnotes).

First, I tried to use the `marginpar` command. Sadly, it cannot be used in math environments as well as `tcbtheorem` environments from the `tcolorbox` package which I happen to use quite frequently.

After trying with `marginpar` I ended up with the `marginnote` package, which does work in math as well as tcbtheorem environments, but there are different problems. The biggest downside is, that margin notes from the `marginnote` command overlap very easily and it's annoying to manually move them up and down until one finds the right spot.

What I am trying to achieve are numbered margin notes which can be referenced (used with the `label/ref` commands), used in math as well as tcbtheorem environments and don't overlap (they should behave like margin notes from the `marginpar` command, which *automatically* move up and down).

Is something like this achievable?

Minimal example (comment out mpar command to see errors):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=10mm,right=65mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{50mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{5mm}

\newcounter{mnotecnt}
\renewcommand\themnotecnt{\textsuperscript{\arabic{mnotecnt}}}
\newcommand\mpar[1]{\refstepcounter{mnotecnt}\themnotecnt\marginpar{\footnotesize\themnotecnt\hspace{1pt}#1}}

\newcommand\mnote[1]{\refstepcounter{mnotecnt}\themnotecnt\marginnote{\footnotesize\themnotecnt\hspace{1pt}#1}}

\newtcbtheorem[]{mytheo}{Theorem}{}{thm}

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.\mpar{Margin note using the marginpar command.}
\blindtext

\begin{mytheo}{}{}
  This is a theorem.\mnote{Margin note using the marginnote package.}
\end{mytheo}

\section*{Problems:}

\begin{mytheo}{}{}
  This is a theorem.\mnote{marginnote} This is a sentence.\mnote{another one}
  (should not overlap!)
\end{mytheo}

\begin{align*}
  \alpha + \beta = \gamma%\mpar{Does not work.} % comment out for error
\end{align*}

\begin{mytheo}{}{}
  This is a theorem.%\mpar{Does not work.} % comment out for error
\end{mytheo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215322/multiple-marginnote-commands-on-the-same-line-in-math-environment and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305022/how-can-i-put-marginnotes-next-to-each-other  Note that this is similar to the approach of the marginfix package.

Comment: Regarding the horizontal offset,  see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269426/wrong-marginnote-positions-inside-a-tikzpicture-with-xelatex

Comment: Amazing work! Thank you very much! I just tested it out and I have two questions: (1) The margin notes automatically switch sides. Is there a way to turn it off?
(2) Is there a way to conveniently place the source code into my preamble? Doing so raises some everypage warnings which result in errors. The warning/error messages are too long to paste into a comment. I can provide a minimal example, but where should I send it to?

The limit of marginnotes per page seems to be 10, right?

Comment: The easy solution is to use oneside documents.  Long source codes can be stored in a separate `.tex` file and read using `\input`.  I really need to update the solution anyway.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573329/so-what-is-the-everypage-package-replacement?r=SearchResults&s=1|45.4525

Comment: ```\input``` didn't work for me earlier, but now it does, weird. Sadly, I don't know how to implement the solution displayed in the last link you provided. I also tried setting the ```onepage``` option in both the report and article class but the margin notes still switch sides. Furthermore, using one of the packages ```xifthen``` or ```calc``` leads to the margin notes being moved down to the end of the page. Is there a fix to this? I would really appreciate an updated version if you have the time to make one!

Answer (score 3):

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report` and `article` classes) provides a variety of what I called "page notes", which include footenotes, either at the page bottom or in the margin, or unnumbered notes in the margin which can extend for over multiple pages.

When using the `article` option `memoir` treats `\chapter` as `\section`, and `\subsection` as `\section`. and so on, so that a document initially written like a book can be typeset as an article. This was the initial idea for an easy conversion from `book/report` to `article`.

However there was no way to typeset an original `article` document using `memoir` except by editing the original document and changing all `\section` to `\chapter`, `\subsection` to `\section`, etc. The following MWE shows how you can use the `memoir` facilities on unedited `article` code.

```
% memarticleprob.tex  SE 630602

\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\let\subsection\section % undo article option change of divisions
\let\section\chapter    % ditto

\footnotesinmargin % set footnotes in the margin

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First}
\lipsum[2]

Some sidefootnoted text.\footnote{Margined footnote.}

\lipsum[4]

Some sidefootnoted text.\footnote{Another margined footnote.}

\subsection{First sub}
\lipsum[2]
\footnotesatfoot % revert to bottom of page footnotes
Some footnoted text.\footnote{Footnote at bottom.}

\end{document}
```

Read the manual (`texdoc memoir` chapter "Page notes") for more on the page notes facilities.

[image]

Comment: Sadly, the footnote environment in the memoir class is a float, so it won't work with either math or tcbtheorem environments. But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @gyha4 Is there any class where `\footnote` works in `math` or `tcbtheorem` environments? If not, what is the equivalent?

Comment: As specified in my question, I am looking for a margin note command that is _numbered_ like a footnote and can be used in math and tcbtheorem environments. The marginnotes package with its marginnote command does work in those environments (since it is not a float) but these notes tend to overlap. The command should not be restricted to any class.

Comment: @gyha4 It seems to me that you are looking for a `\footnote` macro that behaves the same in `math` and `minipage` environments as it does in regular text, putting the footnote text at the bottom of the page and continuous numbering. That is not for me.