# Unexpected output when using chemfig package in Latex

Tags: xetex, chemfig, chemistry

I'd like to write a reaction mechanics in Latex, but the output differs from what I expected.

```
\documentclass{jlreq}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}    
  \schemestart
    \chemfig{@{a}A-@{b}B}
    \arrow{->[\chemfig{@{h}H^{+}}]}
    \chemfig{A}
    \+
    \chemfig{B}
  \schemestop
  \chemmove{
    \draw($(a)!0.5!(b)$)..controls +(90:5mm) and +(90:5mm)..(h);
  }
\end{document}
```

Below is the output(black) and what I want to write(red).
All I know is this occurs when the start/end point of the curve arrow is above the straight arrow.[image]

Comment: You are presumably using platex+dvipdfmx.  If I change the class to `article` so I can use latex, it gives the same wrong output with latex+dvipdfmx , if I delete `[dvipdfmx]` and use pdflatex, it works. So possibly an error in the dvipdfmx back end file, (no time to look now but leaving a comment in case others are checking)

Comment: Testing using XeLaTeX (to force `dvipdfmx` as a backend easily), I see the issue. As @DavidCarlisle says, it's likely a fault in the backend files for `pgf`, which is being used for the drawing.

Comment: @JosephWright I think it is this problem https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229500/tikzmark-and-xelatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks to you, I succeeded to print what I want to write with pdflatex. However, I'm writing a document in Japanese and pdflatex can't deal with Japanese. I guess the best way is making a small size of pdf file of the figure and pasting it on the main tex file, do you know if it is possible or not? I couldn't find any information about the way.

Comment: yes you could do it as a separate file or you could perhaps use luatex which has some support for Japanese or you could use platex and dvips rather then dvipdfmx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried with LuaLatex but it didn't work. In addition, I'm not sure how to make the proper size of figure file. I think I make an A4 size of file when I normally try to make it. I'm really sorry for my ignorance.