# Bibliography on lualatex (with Russian language) is not working

Tags: bibliographies, luatex, russian

I am trying to make a latex file with using the Russian language and bibliography.
It is important that the Russian language should work fine in this document, if I was doing everything in English, it would be easy to find a way how to do it. I want the bibliography to look nice, without the strange words "and", etc.
But it doesn't.
It writes a lot of errors, the first is `Undefined control sequence. \providebibliographyfont`, also `Argument of \MakeUppercase has an extra }. \providebibliographyfont{ISBN}{\MakeUppercase}` and many many others.

I am using **Lualatex** especially for Feynman Diagrams, so I simplified my file to show that it should display 1) Russian, 2) English, 3) Math, 4) Diagrams.
The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[russian, a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\input{for_lua.sty} 
\input{qft_staff.sty}
\input{basichat.sty}
\begin{document}

Раз два три 
One two three
$$\hbar$$
\begin{center}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{center}

% !!! If I uncommit - it doesn't work
%\bibliographystyle{babunsrt-lf}
%\bibliography{bibl_qft}
%\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

But the bibliography doesn't work at all! I don't know, what to do.
Can you please help?

The input files are:

for_lua:

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
% если не ставить вначало, то какой-то пакет загрузится с xcolor и после этого будет выдаавть ошибку при загрузке с нужными мне названиями. Поэтому это в начале.
\usepackage{polyglossia} % Поддержка многоязычности (fontspec подгружается автоматически)
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian} % Язык по-умолчанию русский с поддержкой приятных команд пакета babel
\setotherlanguage{english} % Дополнительный язык = английский (в американской вариации по-умолчанию)
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text} % моноширинный шрифт
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{CMU Typewriter Text} % моноширинный шрифт для кириллицы
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % стандартные лигатуры TeX, замены нескольких дефисов на тире и т. п. Настройки моноширинного шрифта должны идти до этой строки, чтобы при врезках кода программ в коде не применялись лигатуры и замены дефисов
\setmainfont{CMU Serif} % Шрифт с засечками
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Serif} % Шрифт с засечками для кириллицы
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif} % Шрифт без засечек
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfontsf{CMU Sans Serif} % Шрифт без засечек для кириллицы
\usepackage{luacode} % This package provides the \luaexec command and the luacode(*) environments to help with executing luacode
```

qft_staff:

```
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{titlesec} % мб потом удалю, чисто для заголовков на всякий случай постаивил

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n} % толстый mathcal
%%% до символов :::::::::::::: я поставил просто код, с которым можно соединять внизу буквы специально для луа латеха!
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark, arrows.meta}

% WORKAROUND:    
% Definition copied from /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf-via-dvi.def
% Compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229500 and comments!
\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@hboxsynced#1{%
    {%
        \pgfsys@beginscope%
        \setbox\pgf@hbox=\hbox{%
            \hskip\pgf@pt@x%
            \raise\pgf@pt@y\hbox{%
                \pgf@pt@x=0pt%
                \pgf@pt@y=0pt%
                \special{pdf: content q}%
                \pgflowlevelsynccm% 
                \pgfsys@invoke{q -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm}%
                \special{pdf: content -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm q}% translate to original coordinate system
                \pgfsys@invoke{0 J [] 0 d}% reset line cap and dash
                \wd#1=0pt%
                \ht#1=0pt%
                \dp#1=0pt%
                \box#1%
                \pgfsys@invoke{n Q Q Q}%
            }%
            \hss%
        }%
        \wd\pgf@hbox=0pt%
        \ht\pgf@hbox=0pt%
        \dp\pgf@hbox=0pt%
        \pgfsys@hbox\pgf@hbox%
        \pgfsys@endscope%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont} % for checkmark and crossmark symbols
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\tikzset{
    midway mark/.style={pos=0.25, fill=white, inner sep=0pt, font=\scriptsize},
    every subnode/.style={inner sep=1pt}
}
%%% ::::::::::::::
\usepackage{simplewick}
\usepackage{simpler-wick} % для соединений линиями снизу или сверху
\usepackage{tikz-feynman} %рисуют диаграммы фенмана
\usepackage{feynman}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=black},
fermion/.style={draw=black, postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow{>}}}},
vertex/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=black,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt},
}

\NewDocumentCommand\semiloop{O{black}mmmO{}O{above}}
{%
\draw[#1] let \p1 = ($(#3)-(#2)$) in (#3) arc (#4:({#4+180}):({0.5*veclen(\x1,\y1)})node[midway, #6] {#5};)
}
%% Syntax
%\semiloop[fermion][<draw options>]{<first node>}{<second node>}{<angle>}[<label>][<below, default: above>];
\usepackage{bbm} % for \mathbbm
% hbar сам по себе кривой в lualatex, так что для поправки подключаем это
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\hbar\relax
    \DeclareRobustCommand{\hbar}{\text{\normalfont\fontencoding{T2A}\fontfamily{antt}\itshape\symbol{163}}}%
}
```

basichat:

```
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходного текста
%\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы % чет глючит с этим, пока закоммичено - норм собирается
% colors
\definecolor{light-blue}{rgb}{0.8,0.85,1}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{authblk} % для удаления отступов в заголовке, чтобы он был компактным

% для матпикса 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%symbols
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} %math
\usepackage{mathrsfs} % для mathscr
% теоремы
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{definition}{Определение}[section] 
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}
\newtheorem{example}{Пример}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{esint} % various fancy integral symbols
% гиперссылки:
\usepackage{hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{HTML}{0000A0}
\definecolor{linkcolor}{HTML}{0000FF}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH, citecolor=linkcolor, linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=red, colorlinks=true}
% графика:
 \usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{pic/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.png,.jpg, .eps}
\usepackage{caption} % а что без этого летит? (забыл)
\usepackage[section,above,below]{placeins} % управление плавающими объектами (?)
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{float}
% работа с таблицами (?)
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}} % перенос строки в ячейке таблицы при пакете multirow
% предметный указатель и библиография
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
% разметка и стиль (???)
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
%\lhead{ краткое название}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}

\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.5em}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % нормальная нумерация "содержания"
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} %for fraim aroun verbatim
```

bibl_qft:

```
@misc{grozin2005lectures,
      title={Lectures on QED and QCD}, 
      author={Andrey Grozin},
      year={2005},
      eprint={hep-ph/0508242},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      primaryClass={hep-ph}}
@misc{test_rus,
      title={Лекции}, 
      author={Лектор},
      year={2005},}
```

I am very sorry that there is a lot of code here, most of it is not needed, but I am not sure, what I can delete, or what I can't.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't answer why the bibliography isn't working, but there are a number of oddities that should be fixed.  In the file `qft_staff`, `\usetikzlibrary` should not appear before `\usepackage{tikz}`.  In `basichat`, the packages `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, etc. are loaded more than once, and since `amssymb` automatically loads `amsfonts`, it's not necessary to load that separately.  It would be better if all font packages were grouped, so it would be easier to check for duplicates.

Comment: you should clean up your files, you are mixing packages meant for pdflatex (e.g. T2a+fontenc) with packages meant for lualatex. And use biblatex + biber for the bibliography, bibtex can't handle utf8 well.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for the comments, they are also useful!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can you please tell me, what to delete and how to compile? I deleted `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` and `\hbar` stopped working.